# What is the mathematical meaning of loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and I want to understand each step of the following example:

```py
c = tf.square(a - b)                                                           
MSE = tf.reduce_mean(c)  

d = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(a-b),reduction_indices=[1])
e = tf.reduce_mean(d)
```

What is does the value of the `e` variable represent? I want to know the mathematical expression.

Comment: `tf.reduce_mean` simply means that we take the average of the values in `d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
d = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(a-b),reduction_indices=[1])
e = tf.reduce_mean(d)
```

a is real y.
b is predicted y.

mse = avg(sum(square of (a-b) to make +))

So, It can be the loss function how current model can predict y what is being closed real y.

Answer (score 0):

It's the mean; that is, the sum of the given values divided by the number of values.

`tensorflow.math.reduce_mean` is functionally equivalent to `numpy.mean`; it takes the mean value of the tensor it's given.